# Error:insuffcient storage 507 error in Godaddy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, server, shared-hosting

I'm using an woocommerce website. it works before. after adding some products the page loads slowly and shows an error "Insufficient storage 
The method could not be performed on the resource because the server is unable to store the representation needed to successfully complete the request.there is insufficient storage space left in your storage allocation."
But our server has more space 100 Gb memory and 4 Gb ram. we are using Godaddy server. how can I troubleshoot the issue? after removing all products the website loads very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of php memory limit, try to increase memory size from php.ini

example: memory_limit = 256M